# Adding margin left to a img inside of a li

Tags: css

Having a `<li>` with some text and an image to the right of the text inside of the `<li>` with following css:

```
.selectable li {
        margin: 1px;
        padding: 0.4em;
        height: 0.52em;
        line-height: 0.54em;
        position: relative;
        cursor: default;
   }
    .selectable li img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 1px;
        right: 1px;
    }
```

Would like to have a margin to the left of the image so that the end of the text witch sometimes have a few characters more than others doesn't come to close or gets hiden under the image.

Have tried margin-left on the image but for some reason it does not work.

**Update:**

http://jsfiddle.net/upnrL/

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Or at least show some concrete HTML structure, instead of just describing your global document structure.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/upnrL/